# numeric file name match in shell

Tags: linux, shell

I have a bunch files like:

```
0000
0100
0200
0300
0400
0500
0600
0700
0800
0900
1000
1100
1200
1300
1400
```

If I specify a input 8, how to match the files which below 0800? I am using the shell on ubnutu.

**UPDATE**

Sorry, maybe I am not clear.

I have a command which has a parameter used to specify a bunch of input, such as tt***.txt or rrr???.txt. What I want is to specify those files which below 0800.

Answer (score 1):

Using awk:

```
awk -v x=8 'BEGIN{x=sprintf("%04d",x*100);}$1<x' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Bash (assuming that here are files with other names)

```
c=0;
for file in [0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9];
    do 
       if [[ $file> 0800 ]];
       then 
           ((c++));
       fi;
     done;
echo $c;
```

use `for file in [0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]*;` if here are more than 4digit file (it can also get files like 0000aaaa :( )

Answer (score 0):

```
n=8
printf -v filename "%02d00" $n   # 0800
param='????'
for f in $param; do
    [[ $f > $filename ]] && continue
    # do something with $f
    echo $f
done
```

The only proviso is to take care to do string comparison of the filename with the target file and not numeric comparison -- "0800" and "0900" will be treated as octal by default, and of course they are invalid octal numbers. If you want to use numeric comparison, take care to specify the base:

> `(( 10#$f > 10#$filename )) && continue`